# Pygame Reset game

Tags: pygame, reset

I need some help with reseting a game I made. I've got the main loop going and the collision detection working. I'm trying to get an instant restart on the game, one that just resets the score and gets going again - I don't want it to have any user input before it restarts the game again.

MoveAsteroids() simply moves asteroids across the screen which the player has to avoid. It's also the function where score is incremented by 1 each time an asteroid is dodged.

```
def game_loop():
    global score
    while not game_over:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    spaceship.change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    spaceship.change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    spaceship.change = 0

        spaceship.y += spaceship.change
        if spaceship.y > window_height - spaceship.height:     # Creating borders on the window
            spaceship.y = window_height - spaceship.height
        elif spaceship.y < 0:
            spaceship.y = 0

        window.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        MoveAsteroids()
        CollisionDetection()
        Score_display("Score: " + str(score * 100), white)


        pygame.display.update()

def CollisionDetection():
    global score
    spaceship_rect = pygame.Rect(spaceship.x, spaceship.y, spaceship.width, spaceship.height)
    for x in range(1, 5):
        rect = pygame.Rect(asteroids[x].x, asteroids[x].y, asteroids[x].width, asteroids[x].height)
        if spaceship_rect.colliderect(rect):
            pass 

# The part I need help with is this line of code just above^. .colliderect() returns true when a collision happens.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you just want to reset the game. Just do

```
def CollisionDetection():
global score
spaceship_rect = pygame.Rect(spaceship.x, spaceship.y, spaceship.width, spaceship.height)
for x in range(1, 5):
    rect = pygame.Rect(asteroids[x].x, asteroids[x].y, asteroids[x].width, asteroids[x].height)
    if spaceship_rect.colliderect(rect):
        score = 0
        // here you reset your spaceship.x and y to the normal state
```

you could also have a look at [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). It makes collision detection easier and is nice for larger games with it's groups.